# Getting Basic Authentication Headers Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot for my application with Basic Authentication for the rest api.

I would like to get the username and password of the request being authenticated to do some more fine grained authorization tasks. How can I process the HttpHeaders to get the details?

Comment: What is it that you want, please be a bit more elaborate and also add some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation, to get the logged in user as a parameter for your controller function.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<> searchMeta(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserModel activeUser) {
//Do your processing with the UserModel
}
```

Comment: That's not an elaborate question. But, using @EnableWebMvcSecurity, which I think you have if you have basic Authentication, should add the AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver to your configuration and make it possible. You can also get the Principal Object as an Parameter in a Controller function, and retrieve User Data from there. This is described here (http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security).